# Dependencies put twice into Spring Boot (>2.x) jar when using Gradle

Tags: s4sdk

adding Cloud SDK like this for CF:

`compile "com.sap.cloud.s4hana:s4hana-all:${cloudSDKVersion}"
compile ("com.sap.cloud.s4hana.cloudplatform:scp-cf:${cloudSDKVersion}")`

leads to duplicate jars in spring boot jar which is deployed to CF.
examples:

`core-2.3.1.jar
connectivity-2.3.1.jar`

- This leads to :

  - ClassNotFoundExceptions during runtime
  - prevents cf push commands with error:

    `Comparing local files to remote cache...
    Aborting push: File BOOT-INF/lib/core-2.3.1.jar has been modified since the start of push. Validate the correct state of the file and try again.
    FAILED`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

gradle skips the component name when building the boot package.

After some googling around this was the solution:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/10778

```
bootJar {
    rootSpec.filesMatching('**/*.jar', { jar ->
        String groupId = jar.file.parentFile.parentFile.parentFile.parentFile.name
        jar.name = "$groupId-${jar.name}"
    })
}
```